# JQuery search and compare part of word in array

Tags: jquery, string-comparison

I'm beginner with JQuery, and I have my first issues ! ;)
I want to search particuliar word/number from array in many url.

- I list URLs in an "aLinks" array.
- The URLs of aLinks are in the form "../page/article?359&lng=5"
- I have a second table with reference values to look for (e.g.: ["359","686"])

I tried several methods, but **the match is only found with the full URL, and never with only "359"** which is one of the values I’m looking for...

I'm supposed it' because isn't a substring (no space in the sentence) ?
What I can do, use search with regex? match?

```
/* 01 - Parse links in aLinks array */

  jQuery(document).ready(function parseLink() {
        
    var aLinks = $('a.link.article').map( function() {
        return $(this).attr('href');
    }).get();
   
/*  02 - Loop and search over array */
  
  var refArray = ['359', '../page/article?686&lng=5'];
  
  $.each(aLinks, function(idx, value) {
        if ($.inArray(value, refArray) !== -1) {
            console.log('MATCH : ' + value);

/*
    Only the second index works... because isn't a substring ?
*/

        } else {
            console.log('NOT MATCH: ' + value);
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks !
Best regards,
Fiz

EDIT : With the solution of cheesyMan, I just added concatenation with urlStart and urlEnd :

```
urlStart = '../page/article?';
urlEnd = '&lng='

$.each(aLinks, function(idx, val) {
    let matching = false;
    for (let i = 0; i < compare.length; i++) {
        if (val.includes(urlStart + compare[i] + urlEnd)) {
          console.log(`${val} MATCHED!`);
          matching = true;
        }
    }

        if (!matching) console.log(`${val} DID NOT MATCH...`)
        })
```

It's OK, Thanks a lot at all !!

Comment: Provide some clearer sample of the arrays you're comparing. Did not understand if you need to compare your `aLinks` against an array like `['389', '686', '423',....]` (as you say in the question) or like `['389', '../page/article?686&lng=5' ,'686', '423',....]` as you write in the snippet.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example It may also be best to take the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour. I would also advise reviewing: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/

Comment: Cheesyman : Ok sorry, I have added full URL in snippet for show that only this entry match. It's ID's only in array, not URL

Twisty : Ok, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `$.each()` loop you compare each *link* inside `aLinks[]` with the values inside `refArray[]`, using [strict equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality).

So, each value of the first array (`aLinks`) must be **strictly equal to** (`===`) one of the elements of the second array (`refArray`).

I think you need a nested loop inside $.each (to compare each link against each of the references) and to compare them with [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes). Also [`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) could be useful in cases like this.

I've used some fake arrays in this snippet, don't know if they fit to your data.

```js
const compare = [
  '389', '423', '../page/article?915&lng=5', '212', '../page/article?686&lng=3'
]

const links = [
  '../page/article?359&lng=5', '../page/article?389&lng=2', '../page/article?459&lng=4', '../page/article?212&lng=1', '../page/article?915&lng=5'
]


$.each(links, function(idx, val) {
  let matching = false;
  for (let i = 0; i < compare.length; i++) {
    if (val.includes(compare[i])) {
      console.log(`${val} MATCHED!`);
      matching = true;
    }
  }

  if (!matching) console.log(`${val} DID NOT MATCH...`)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !
I have encapsuled the begin and the end of the url (doesn't change) beacuse that ID 9369 for example is not returned as true, whereas only 369 should be. And I have only ID in my "compare" arrays, must clearier (and I probaly populated with JSON in future.)
You'r make my day Thanks !

```
urlStart = '../page/article?';
urlEnd = '&lng='
$.each(aLinks, function(idx, val) {
_______

if (val.includes(urlStart + compare[i] + urlEnd)) {

______
````

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark as accepted the answer - if any - that answers/solves your question. And to upvote all answers that are useful for your problem.

Comment: I can't upvote, it's my first login on SO :/, I closed the ticket tomorrow, thanks :)

Comment: You can anyway mark as accepted an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Here I have a script that searches the #SUuL1 input. From the #uList1 and replaces it with a mark tag. Not exactly what you are looking for, but it's something you can fiddle around with. Indeed the part that you are looking for is the RegExp. // search for all ✌️

```
let searched = document.getElementById("SUuL1").value.trim();
if (searched !== "") {
    let text = document.getElementById("uList1").innerHTML;
    let re = new RegExp(searched+ "(?![^<>]*>)","ig"); // search for all
    let newText = text.replace(re, `<mark>${searched}</mark>`);
    document.getElementById("uList1").innerHTML = newText;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Kip, ! The answer of cheesyMan seems work but I test your solution tomorrow !

Comment: Well, what I gave you still needs a bit of work and steps to get the perfect integration, it was just something where you could start with.  ✌️